Vercel serverless functions timing out after X amount of time due to DB connections
Logs on Vercel are overflowing with errors ("Task timed out after 15.02 seconds"). About 2k per hour.
To give you an understanding of the architecture, I host a Next.js 14 app on Vercel (pro plan). Serverless functions execute SSR code (lambda functions) which are tasked with fetching data from the database (RDS Postgres with PGBouncer hosted on AWS ECS) and rendering components, and Prisma ORM handles the connections inside the app.
My best guess is that the lambda functions running inside of Next.js (that each opens 7 connections to the db) are using up all the allowed connections. In CloudWatch I can see a lot of these closing because: client unexpected eof (age=XXX) errors. (where XXX = between 300s and 7200s). The number of these errors in CloudWatch is almost equal to the corresponding number of "task timeout errors" from Vercel, 2k/hour
Here are my pgbouncer values:

pg_bouncer_default_pool_size: 20
pg_bouncer_idle_transaction_timeout: 300
pg_bouncer_max_client_conn: 1500
pg_bouncer_max_connections: 1000
pg_bouncer_max_instances: 3
pg_bouncer_min_pool_size: 5
pg_bouncer_reserve_pool_size: 60

Things I've tried:

Scaled the allocation of CPU/MEM for the ECS (from 0.5cpu -> 1cpu, 512MB -> 1GB) basically increased the instance from db.t4g.micro to db.t4g.small
added the pg_bouncer_idle_transaction_timeout [somehow I think this only made it worse]
Increased the timeout value for Vercel serverless functions to 15s
made sure pgbouncer is in transaction mode and that I've appended &pgbouncer=true to the Prisma connection string
Increased the Vercel function CPU from Basic to Performance
Made sure Prisma client is being instantiated outside all functions and used globally across the entire app as per their docs

I'm only a FE engineer so all this AWS/database stuff is a bit over my head.
